# Consulta de conversión de datos

Tags: r

Tengo una consulta como puedo convertir esta estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a esta siguiente estructura fácilmente en R?:

[image: Grupos Grupos calificación 1 grupo1 15 2 grupo1 9 3 grupo1 16 4 grupo1 10 5 grupo1 18 6 grupo1 9 7 grupo1 19 8 grupo1 10 9 grupo1 11 10 grupo1 14 11 grupo1 11 12 grupo1 17 13 grupo1 16 14 grupo1 15 15 grupo1 13 16 grupo1 14 17 grupo1 17 18 grupo1 16 19 grupo2 17 20 grupo2 19 21 grupo2 14 22 grupo2 13 23 grupo2 15 24 grupo2 20 25 grupo2 20 26 grupo2 21 27 grupo2 17 28 grupo2 13 29 grupo2 22 30 grupo2 22 31 grupo2 19 32 grupo2 17 33 grupo2 15 34 grupo2 14]

Answer (score 3):

Con un `data.frame` similar a lo que muestras:

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(grupo1=runif(5), grupo2=runif(5))
df
     grupo1    grupo2
1 0.4512674 0.7013460
2 0.7837798 0.6404389
3 0.7096822 0.2666797
4 0.3817443 0.8154215
5 0.6363238 0.9829869
```

La forma tradicional con R es usar `reshape()`:

```
# Ajustamos el formato ancho al largo
new_df <- reshape(df,
                  varying=list(1:2),
                  v.names=c("Valor"),
                  times=c("grupo1","grupo2"),
                  direction="long")[,1:2]
# Hemos seleccionado solo las 2 columnas y le configuramos el nombre
new_df <- setNames(new_df, c('Grupos', 'Calificacion'))
# Eliminamos el nombre de fila
rownames(new_df) <- NULL
new_df

   Grupos Calificacion
1  grupo1    0.4512674
2  grupo1    0.7837798
3  grupo1    0.7096822
4  grupo1    0.3817443
5  grupo1    0.6363238
6  grupo2    0.7013460
7  grupo2    0.6404389
8  grupo2    0.2666797
9  grupo2    0.8154215
10 grupo2    0.9829869
```

Por otro lado con `tidyverse` se puede hacer lo mismo de una forma mucho más simple y clara mediante `pivot_longer()`:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(grupo1, grupo2)) %>% 
  select(Grupos=name, Calificacion=value)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me resulto super útil